# How do I include the field label in a jquery Validate error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am displaying my jquery validate errors at the top of the page. I want to include the text value of the label associated with each invalid field next to each message.  How is this done.  Here is my jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reqAccount").validate({
            errorClass: "error-text",
            validClass: "valid",
            errorLabelContainer: "#errorList",
            wrapper: "li ",
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).addClass("error-input").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
             },
             unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).removeClass("error-input").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
             }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you might be able to use `showErrors`:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
      //use the fn params to get a map of current errors,
      //then append to your <li> elements
   }
});
```

Ref. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate under 'options' tab.

Comment: That makes sense, but the documentation for showErrors is sparse.  How do I know what attributes errorMap contains in order to even know how to append to it?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I ultimately updated the messages to include the text value of the label.  The ids of the text field were found in the errorMap, so I used them to find the label with a similar ID and appended them to the errorList.  Please comment if there's a better way to do this.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reqAccount").validate({
        errorClass: "error-text",
        validClass: "valid",
        errorLabelContainer: "#errorList",
        wrapper: "li class='indent error-text'",
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            var i = 0;
            var labelText = new Array(this.numberOfInvalids());
            $.each(errorMap, function(name, value) {
                labelText[i] = $("#" + name + "Label").text();
                i++;
            });
            i = 0;
            $.each(errorList, function(name, value) {
                this.message = labelText[i] + " " + this.message;
                i++;
        });
            this.defaultShowErrors();

         },

        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).addClass("error-input").addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
         },
         unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass("error-input").removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: The line: this.message = labelText[i] + " " + this.message; could be included in first $.each() itself. There seems to be no need of second $.each(). Or are you supposed to include something from errorList?

Comment: @Ritesh - The first $.each is intended to iterate over the errorMap and create an array of field id values.  The text of the label related with each field is retrieved using the id from the errorMap.  The second $.each iterates over the errorList, which is the object that displays the errors.  I add the text that was retrieved in the first $.each to the errorList values.

Answer (score 2):

Coder thanks for the answer that you posted, the showErrors code you posted helped me out a lot. However, I wasn't able to get it to work for me with the onfocusout set to true.  I had to modify your code a little bit, and hopefully this will help anyone else out there who is dealing with this same problem.

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
                var i = 0;
                var labelText = new Array(this.numberOfInvalids());

                $.each(errorMap, function(name, value) {
                    //I had to change the following line to get the for attribute of the 
                    //label that matches the id of the name
                    var label = $("label[for='" + $('#' + name).attr('id') + "']").text();
                    labelText[i] = label;
                    i++;
                 });
                i = 0;
                $.each(errorList, function(name, value) {
                    //This is where I ran into issues.  With the code you had earlier, the labelText kept
                    //getting appended every time I would change focus from an input.  To get rid of that
                    //I had to run a couple of checks
                    var semi = labelText[i].indexOf(':');
                    var requiredString = 'This field is required';
                    var check = labelText[i].indexOf(requiredString); 

                    if (check != -1) {
                        if (semi != -1 && labelText[i].indexOf(':', semi + 1) != -1) {
                            var indexOfSemi = labelText[i].indexOf(':'); 
                            labelText[i] = labelText[i].substr(0, indexOfSemi); console.log(labelText[i]);
                            this.message = hold + ": " + this.message;
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.message = labelText[i] + " " + this.message;d
                        i++;
                    }
                });
                this.defaultShowErrors();
            },
```

Just wanted to say thanks, and hopefully this'll help someone else out as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.validator.messages.required = function (param, input) {
     return 'The ' + $("label[for='"+ input.name +"'].lblRequired").text()
     + ' field is required';
}
```

I use this and it works perfectly for me. When you select the corresponding label with jQuery, be sure to add an additional identifier to your label (in my case I added the class ".lblRequired"). When the validator fires, it creates new labels with the same "for" which associates them to the inputs. So if you don't add a class or another way to identify your original labels, you'll end up with a mess as you select the wrong label for subsequent validations and the labels will continue to compound with error messages.