# Getting validation error but also form is submitting using ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have one form and fields are Name, Email, Message.I am inserting data in the database with the help of ajax and I am using Jquery validator for validation. When I clicked on submit button without filled the fields then I am getting the validation error but the form is also submitting. First, It should check the data in the field proper or not. If data is proper then the form will submit otherwise it will display the validation error. Would you help me in this?

**HTML**

```
    <form name="contact_form" id="form_sub" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
      <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br />
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
      <span class="success">Message was Sent</span>
    </form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

// When the browser is ready...
  $(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("form[name='contact_form']").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
           name:{ required: true,
                 minlength:3,
                 maxlength:30
                },

            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

            message:{
          required: true,
          minlength:10,
          maxlength:500
          }
         },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            name: 
            {
                required:"Please enter your name",
                minlength:"Please enter min 3 character"
                },

            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            message: {
                required:"Please enter your message",
                minlength:"Please enter min 10 character",
                maxlength:"Not more then 500 character"
            }

        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });


      $(function () {
        $('#form_sub').submit('click', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'demo2.php',
            data: $('#form_sub').serialize(),
            success: function () {
        $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();

            }
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
```

**PHP**

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$user_message=$_POST['message'];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "demo";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO contactus(name, email, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$user_message')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Enstage. That I will do after some time.

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15625824/916000

Comment: try to submit form like this: '$('#form_sub').submit()'

Comment: @Nidhi in the jquery validation plugin documentation, it says that should be avoided to prevent an infinite loop. The correct way to do it is `form.submit()`. https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-too-much-recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your submit function contents into your submit handler:

```
submitHandler: function ( form ) {
        $.ajax( {
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'demo2.php',
          data: $( '#form_sub' ).serialize(),
          success: function () {
            $( '.success' ).fadeIn( 200 ).show();
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Taha Paksu. Working for me. I need one more help in this. Can we make the fields empty after submitting the form? Because now I am submitting the form but records are also showing in the fields.

Comment: use `$("#form_sub").find("input, select").val("");` and if you also use textarea, add this too `$("#form_sub").find("textarea").text("");`

Comment: Should I add Inside success function?

Comment: I tried below code inside Success function and working perfectly
    $('input[type="text"], input[type="email"] ,textarea').val('');