# How do i send data to php and get the result using jquery submitHandler()

Tags: php, jquery

I'm learning Jquery, so that it's not easy for me to Implement what i want.

I'v a html form which validate using jquery validation plugin. So after validate is complete I want to send the form data to php page. In php page all data will be go to mysql database and after successfully inserted it should be show a successful message which (**success message**) will be get back to jquery submitHandler() so that I can show the success message in same page. Can you please show my how can i do this ?

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});
```

Note : Without Alert message

Comment: You're using the jQuery Validate plugin. You need to look into the documentation of that plugin, not only of jQuery generally. See http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: @hakre is it possible to send data to php and get the result in request page after validate ?

Comment: No, but it is possible to disable browser-form-submition, serailizing of the form-data, sending the form-data via ajax request to page, get back the result - all together after validate.

Comment: sure it is, just send the data using $.ajax and then load() the returned data into a div on your result page, from the call back function.

Comment: @hakre can show me an example ?

Comment: This is one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11469666/367456 - for example.