# RedirectToAction in a single-page application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I have a fairly simple `single-page application` that uses `AJAX` to load and replace contents of the page. The application should allow user to add phone numbers to a customer. After user loads a `view` to add a new phone number by clicking on `Ajax.ActionLink` on customers page he can submit an `AJAX` form with a number to be added, and if the value is a number he should be redirected back to the customers page. Here is where I stuck, how do I return a result of another `action`? It seems that I can't use `RedirectToAction` since it returns `302` and the browser initiates a `GET` request which is not allowed verb in my situation, the browser gets back `404` as a result.

So I have two `controllers`, `PhoneBookController` and `CustomersController`. User loads `Customers/Details` `view` and clicks on `Ajax.ActionLink` which calls `PhoneBook/Add` `action`, this `action` returns a `view` with an `AJAX` form which is being submitted to `PhoneBook/Create` `action`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Phone ph, string Caller)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ph.Active = true;
        db.PhoneBook.Add(ph);
        db.SaveChanges();
 /*->*/ return RedirectToAction("Details", "Customers", new { Id = ph.CustomerId }); //what should be used instead?
    }

    return PartialView("Add", ph);
}
```

How this type of tasks usually are accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using ajax, you could return the URL from your action and have it redirected in javascript:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Phone ph, string Caller)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ph.Active = true;
        db.PhoneBook.Add(ph);
        db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(new { success = true, redirecturl = Url.Action("RedirectedAction") });
}
```

When you define your ActionLink, specify the success handler:

```
new AjaxOptions
{
     OnSuccess = "onSuccess"
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function onSuccess(result) {
    if (result.success == true)
    {
        window.location = result.redirecturl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it's shouldn't be the `window.location` but I've got your idea. The only problem here that if the `ModelState.IsValid` I'm going to send back `JSON` and if not, then the same view should be loaded with validation errors. and how do I understand which one was returned? `Ajax.ActionLink("Add New Number", "", new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "main-content", Url = Url.Action("Add", "PhoneBook", new { CustomerId = Model.BaseCustomer.Id })})`, so I can add lets say `OnSuccess = "(function (response) { ... })(data)"` but how to tell what the response bears a view or an URL?

Comment: @Jyrkka I would just pass the json data back and update the UI afterwards. You can output validation errors in this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987752/jquery-post-and-unobtrusive-ajax-validation-not-working-mvc-4/28989183#28989183

Comment: It seems that I need your help here also, obviously `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form)` cannot be used since $form is not defined. if I pass in the `document` instead of `$form`, error messages are shown only after second click on the submit button?

Comment: @Jyrkka it's basically just the form returned with jQuery i.e.  `$form = $('form');` or another selector.

Comment: I thought that it is, but it didn't work as I expected...Do you have an idea, why the errors dodn't appear before second submit?

Comment: @Jyrkka Sorry, I don't. It's worth creating another question, just that way someone else will answer and might have a better idea. A simple example improves the chances of an answer too.