# Check if an input is empty in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i have a dynamic form so i have no idea which kind of input there will be every time and i need to handle that, so i've done something like this

```
<div id="repond-questionnaire" class="modal fade in" style="display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Questionnaire de Test</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="questionnaire_here">
                <form method="post" id="questionnaire_form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text"><h3>Who are you?</h3></label>
                        <textarea type="text" name="80" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Text..." required="" value=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="focusedInput"><h3>How old are you?</h3></label>
                        <input type="number" name="81" class="form-control" placeholder="Number..." required="" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="focusedInput"><h3>What is your email?</h3></label>
                        <input type="email" name="82" class="form-control" placeholder="Email..." required="" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="focusedInput"><h3>Do you like our website?</h3></label>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="input-lg"><input type="radio" name="83" value="Oui">Oui</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="input-lg"><input type="radio" name="83" value="Non">Non</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="sumbit" id="sumbit" value="Sumbit" class="btn btn-success"></form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#repond-questionnaire').on('click', '#sumbit', function() {
                // here i need to check if all inputs are empty or not 
                //check if they have a valid input or not for security
                //because after i will send everything and upload them to the data base
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "user/sumbit_answers.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: $('#questionnaire_form').serialize(),
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#sumbit').val("Sumbiting...");
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#questionnaire_form')[0].reset();
                            if (data == 'exit_failure') {
                                alert("something wrong happened");
                            } else {
                                $('#questionnaire_here').empty();
                                $('#questionnaire_here').html(data);
                            }
                        }
                    });

            });
            $('#repond-questionnaire').on('click', '#close', function(event) {
                $('#questionnaire_here').empty();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

and i'm obliged to do this because somehow the events of the form are blocked ( even though i'm not using `event.preventdefault()`, my form input are all like this

```
<input type='$type' name='$row[cid]' class='form-control' placeholder='$type...' required value=''>
```

Comment: What should occur if all `<input>` elements have values, or all `<input>` elements do not have values?

Comment: @guest271314 i want send data only when all input elements have values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `required` attribute is already set at `<input>` elements within `<form>`, you can use `.checkValidity()` of `<form>` element.

Additionally you can include `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `[^\s]+` to require at least a single character at `<input>` elements. Adjust `RegExp` to meet requirement.

```html
<form name="form">
  <input name="input1" type="text" pattern="[^\s]+" required>
  <input name="input2" type="text" pattern="[^\s]+" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  document.forms.form.querySelector("[type=submit]")
  .onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.form.checkValidity());
    // if (this.form.checkValidity()) { /* all <input> elements have `.value */ }
    // else { /* all <input> elements do not have `.value */ }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @SafiyZaghbane Not sure what you are attempting to convey?

Comment: `// if (this.form.checkValidity()) { /* all <input> elements have .value */ } // else { /* all <input> elements do have .value */ }` i'm confused about what did you say here .. it seems like you said the same thing in the `if` and `else`

Comment: The `else` block is for when all `<input>` elements do not have `.value`.

Comment: i'm sorry but i still can't understand how can i use that

Comment: @SafiyZaghbane What do you mean?  `javascript` at Answer is one possible solution to your Question.`if(DOMFormElementReference.checkValidity()) {//do ajax stuff}`. Are the `<input>` elements within a `<form>` element? Can you include full `html` at Question? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i've add one of the forms which may be in the modal that i'm supposed to handle, should i replace "DOMFormElementReference" by my form id?

Comment: it took me a second to understand your answer but a day to apply it, i've found that i had a problem catching the right form and thats why it didn't work for me, i think your answer is the best for this case

Answer (score 0):

```
var text_input=$("[type=text]");
var password_input=$("[type=password");
var radio_input=$("[type=radio]");
var checkbox_input=$("[type=checkbox]");
var select=$("<select>");
var textarea=$("<textarea>");
```

Then you have to do for loop for each one to check and apply your validation according to that field

Call ajax after validation (the following link will help you)
[jQuery Form Validation before Ajax submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469616/jquery-form-validation-before-ajax-submit)

Comment: but maybe there will be much type=text or other types, and can you please show me how would i do that with a for loop?

Comment: for(i=0;i<text_input.length;i++){if (text_input[i].value==''){var error=false;}}

Comment: This is for example you will get array I'm each field if you have more than one of that type.

Comment: Okay i'll try and test this solution, but im wondering why without the Ajax function when i click on sumbit it tells me that some fields need to be filled but with Ajax, it ignores that errors and send the data directly to be posted

Comment: Because it will do the Ajax call directly in somewhere you have to return false if there is incomplete fields else do Ajax call

Comment: there is no way i can catch that errors do the ajax only if the form doesn't show any errors ?

Comment: You can build the function for validatiton then let this function return false or true according to the validation , and then with in your click call this function if true call Ajax if false don't call Ajax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469616/jquery-form-validation-before-ajax-submit

Comment: May be this post will help you try to understand the idea of answers to use it in your way

Comment: I think this is what i want, i'll accept your answer but please add that to your answer so everyone else who have the same problem will find it

Comment: You mean the link ?

Comment: yeah or what ever you may add

Comment: I hope that I helped you